# Помогите решить проблему с Console.Read()! Почему с ReadLine всё хорошо работает, а с Read выдаёт ошибку CS0029?

Tags: c#, readline

Писал вчера код для решения задачи о новых правах(New drivers license на SoloLearn). И встретил ошибку, решение которой вызывает у меня затруднение. Прошу помощи у обитателей StackOverflow и надеюсь, что мне кто-нибудь ответит.
Я закомментировал там ошибку с вводом строки. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему ReadLine - можно, а Read - нельзя.

Вот сам код(заранее прошу прощения если что-то по глупости сделал не так):

```
using System;
/*
Ввод,который есть сейчас:
Aaron
1
Jane 
Max 
Olivia 
Sam

Ввод,который нужен:
Aaron
1
Jane Max Olivia Sam
*/
 namespace Dcoder
 {
   public class Program
   {
     public static void Main()
     {
       string[] People = new string[5];
       People[0] = Console.ReadLine();
       int interw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       for(int i = 1; i < People.Length; i++)
        //People[i] = Console.Read(); - CS0029
        People[i] = Console.ReadLine();
       string hero = People[0];
       Array.Sort(People);
      /* for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
        Console.WriteLine($"Sorted massive [{i}] = {People[i]}");
      Console.WriteLine("Hero is " + hero);*/
       int hIndx = Array.IndexOf(People, hero) + 1;
       Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling((double)hIndx / (double)interw) * 20);
     }
   }
 }
```

P. S. Комментарии, выводящие на экран значение переменных нужны были мне при попытке отладки программы, я не стал их стирать, может быть, они помогут Вам.

Comment: Потому что `Console.Read` не возвращает строку. Это можно узнать в документации https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ещё раз прошу прощения, но я не смог найти то, как реализовать здесь ввод. Не могли бы Вы меня просветить?

Comment: нет, не ясно что вы хотите. Отредактируйте вопрос или задайте новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadLine считывает тебе строку, до того момента, пока ты не нажмёшь Enter, Read же читаешь лишь 1 символ

Comment: А если ты хочешь, чтобы у тебя в массиве хранились объекты по индексам, а не в одной строке, то сделай что-то такое: string tmp = people.Splite(' '); где people -> строка, тем самым, в tmp у тебя будет массив имён (tmp[0] -> Jane, tmp[1] -> Max, и т.д.)